# Java Retrieving The Correct Object

Tags: java, class, object

This program may seem overcomplicated for a simple task but this is a simplified
version of my more complex program because I'm having a very specific problem.

So if I enter the Commands:

ADD     //Command "ADD", adds the phones to the array list in class PhoneShop

DISPLAY //Command "DISPLAY", then the next lines will appear, which are correct

0 Samsung

1 Google

2 Sony

3 LG

4 iPhone

BUY 0  //Command "BUY #", means buy the phone at the #th index of the array list

DISPLAY //Command "DISPLAY", then the next lines will appear, which are correct

0 Google

1 Sony

2 LG

3 iPhone

RETURN  //Command "RETURN", returns the last bought phone to the end of the array list

DISPLAY //Command "DISPLAY", then the next lines will appear, the last line is incorrect

0 Google

1 Sony

2 LG

3 iPhone

4 Google

What I want is for the last output line to be the last phone purchased. So the expected would be:

0 Google

1 Sony

2 LG

3 iPhone

4 Samsung

I think my issue is I'm returning the 0th index of the new array list (after a phone is purchased). I want to return the 0th index of the old array list (before a phone is purchased).

I also have another issue where if the returned command is entered in 2 times in a row, for example, my program will return "the last phone bought" twice. To fix this I know I should update the last phone bought reference variable to null but I'm not sure exactly to to implement that. So for example, this would occur:

ADD

BUY 0

RETURN

RETURN

DISPLAY

0 Google

1 Sony

2 LG

3 iPhone

4 Google

5 Google

PhoneShopSimulator Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PhoneShopSimulator
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        PhoneShop shop = new PhoneShop();
        ArrayList<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<Phone>();
        int index = 0;

        phones.add(new Phone("Samsung"));
        phones.add(new Phone("Google"));
        phones.add(new Phone("Sony"));
        phones.add(new Phone("LG"));
        phones.add(new Phone("iPhone"));

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (input.hasNextLine()) 
        {
             String line = input.nextLine(); 
             Scanner commandLine = new Scanner(line);
             String word = commandLine.next();

             if (word.equals("QUIT"))
             {
                 return;
             } 

             else if (word.equals("DISPLAY"))
             {
                  shop.displayInventory();  
             } 

             else if (word.equals("ADD"))
             {
                  shop.addPhones(phones);
             } 

             else if (word.equals("BUY"))
             {
                  index = Integer.parseInt(commandLine.next());
                  shop.buyPhone(index);
             }

             else if (word.equals("RETURN"))
             {  
                  shop.returnPhone(shop.getObjectPhone(index));
             }

             else
             {
                  System.out.println("Invalid Command");
             }
             commandLine.close();
        }
        input.close(); 
        }
 }
```

PhoneShop Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PhoneShop 
{

private Phone p;
private ArrayList<Phone> phones;

public PhoneShop()
{
    ArrayList<Phone> array = new ArrayList<Phone>();
    phones = array; 
}

public Phone getObjectPhone(int index)
{
    p = phones.get(index);
    return p;
}

public void addPhones(ArrayList<Phone> newPhones)
{
    phones.addAll(newPhones);
}

public ArrayList<Phone> getPhones()
{
    return phones;
}

public Phone buyPhone(int index)
{
    if (index >= 0 && index < phones.size())
    {           
        p = phones.remove(index);
        return p;
    }
    return null;
}

public Phone returnPhone(Phone p)
{
    if (p != null)
    {
        phones.add(p);

    }
    return null;
}


public void displayInventory()  
{
    for (int i = 0; i < phones.size(); i++)
    {
         Phone referenceP = new Phone(phones.get(i).getModel());
         System.out.println(i + " " + referenceP.display());
    }
}

}
```

Phone Class:

```
public class Phone 
{

private String model;

public Phone(String model)
{
    this.model = model;
}

public String getModel() 
{
    return model;
}

public String display()
{
    return model;
}
}
```

Comment: Maintain another ArrayList containing the Phones Purchased,

Comment: Thanks your simple recommendation helped me a ton. I've fixed my problems